# Simple form custom input with acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, acts-as-taggable-on

I have some problems with Simple_form and acts-as-taggable-on.

I have a object "Pictogram" with some tags like "*door*" and "*emergency*"

I use this code in my form

```
= f.input :tag_list
```

When I edit my Pictogram the system delete my comma and display my text_field like that "door emergency" if i save my two tags are deleted and replaced by one tag "door emergency"

I'm looking for a solution on the net and many peoples advise to create a custom input in simple_form but I don't where to begin.

I create a file tag_input.rb in app/inputs and I add this code

```
class TagInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
 def input(wrapper_options)

 end
end
```

But now I'm lost.

Sorry for my English, it's not my native language

Answer (score 14):

Here's what you do based on [this](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/wiki/Add-a-tag-field-to-forms-in-Rails--4.2-and-above)

```
= f.input :tag_list, input_html: {value: @something.tag_list.to_s}
```

Comment: This should really be in the README... in fact having usage with forms in general should be in the README!

Comment: As suggested edit queue is full, recommend to use: `f.input :tag_list, value: f.object.tag_list.join(",")`

Answer (score 1):

Custom input contains simple form tags

Check out this wiki https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Adding-custom-input-components

Inside you can build comma separated string of values

```
value = object.tags.join(',')
text_field_tag attribute_name, value
```

Something like that, don't have a simple form nearby, so can't debug this code.

But the main idea I think is clear